# How to open a file in the default external editor on Qt/Android

Tags: android, c++, qt

I have a Qt application ported to Android 4.4 (using Qt Creator 3.0.1, Qt 5.2.1).

In a QLabel, I create a link to a web page `<a href=http://www.google.fr>Test</a>`. When user clicks "Test", google page is opened in the user's default selected browser. Fine.

In the same QLabel, I create a link to a file/folder `<a href=file:///sdcard/Documents>Test</a>`. When user clicks "Test"...nothing happens.

If I open Chrome from the Android phone and type file:///sdcard/Documents in the URL field, the folder is displayed correctly.

Note that my manifest has `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` (and also `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`).

How can I simply have the Android system open a file/folder in the default viewer?

Answer (score 1):

I finally gave up....I called Java code from my C++ program to open a text editor. Something like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File(fileName);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "text/plain");

myActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

It works, but remains less trivial than using a simple file hyperlink....
Good point is that it opens default selected text editor rather than web browser.